# JBoss not responding to valid URLs

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x

I encountered strange behavior of an JBoss AS 7 on linux server. When I deploy war with my application, the server doesn't respond for valid HTTP requests for this app. When I try to GET a valid URL, I can see in logs, that backend functions (e.g. DAO methods) are called, debug logs shows that subsequent tags in my JSF are rendered, I even can see a message `Rendering View index.xml`, but the response never reaches the client. 
When I use a non-existent URL (e.g. `index.asd`) response is 404 and when I use a wrong page name (e.g. `inswxasd.xhtml`) the response is 500. Thus it fails only with valid requests.

I tried to connect both remotely (using firefox) and locally (with `wget`) and I reproduced the problem. The strange thing is that I deploy the war that I already used and then it worked.

**EDIT 1:**

I've just noticed that when I send a request to, the server process takes 200% of CPU. Additionally it happens for only one application with stack: Hibernate, Spring, JSF 2.0, Primefaces.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is [pastie with jstack output](http://pastie.org/private/5ibhlq0uyycbwhnrivqqaq) (`jstack -l -F <PID>`). All threads are blocked.

Additionally I noticed (using `top` and dumping stack of the JBoss process) that the problem is most probably caused by a thread called `http--0.0.0.0-8080-1`. Any ideas?

Comment: *"the server process takes 200% of CPU."* Apparently it's running in an infinite loop somewhere. Hard to say where since you didn't show any code :) Run a debugger/profiler to nail it down.

Comment: Thanks, the problem occures only on the server. Maybe you know any linux console tool for JVM monitoring (threads, open files etc.)?

Comment: You could use VisualVM or JConsole to see which threads are blocking. This is the first I've heard of this though.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something console-based (as I don't have graphical environment on the server).

Comment: It's tough to say what it might be. Is it possible to remove Spring from the mix just for testing purposes? I see some references to ActiveMQ in the jstack output, but in AS 7 HornetQ is used for messaging. Might have nothing to do with it, just pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. I reverted the database to previous state, and it started to work. Apparently there was a problem in the data that caused this infinite loop. Now we need to find it, but as it is reproducible, I'll manage.